# Is is possible to achieve the below visual in power-bi?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have the data in the following format:
[image]

Is it possible to build a visual that looks somewhat like this?

[image]

If any modifications or transformations to the data are to be done, please let me know. The end goal is to have a visual that looks like the one above.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a custom kind of visual which need to create separately and import it in PBI.
Or you can explore more visual in "Get More Visual" option in Power BI and select any visual which is close to your need.
You can get more visual option near to visual pane when you click on 3 ellipsis

[image]

Comment: Hi, I tried exploring the market place. But, couldn't find one which works for me. So, I thought I'd ask the community once.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a scatter plot, with an imported custom visual for the icon you presented in your screengrab. You will likely need some custom CSS or formatting, but it could be done. This falls more under the realm of custom UI design development.